# Calculation within a string field MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have been attempting to edit/add a value string column (process) within a table.

The current values in the string is as follow:

```
1:38,25:39,41:101
```

What I want to do is add 1000 to every value after "X:" so after the query the values should read:

```
1:1038,25:1039,41:1101
```

I have looked at CONCAT but that seems to only insert a value into a string within certain parameters. Any ideas?

Comment: Now you know why normalization helps!

Comment: @Paul does the example provided in question show single row or multiple rows separated by comma?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CAST` `CONCAT` and `SUBSTRING_INDEX` functions to get the required output, e.g.:

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, ':', 1), ":", (CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, ':', -1) AS UNSIGNED) + 1000))
FROM test;
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59f15d/10/0)**.

Comment: The data in question is **not** in separate rows. Hence, this doesn't answer the given question.

Answer (score 0):

Use of variables can help you achieve what you want:

```
  select @pre := SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`column_name`, ':', 1), '0', -1), 
    @post := SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`column_name`, ':', 2), '0', -1), 
    concat(@pre,":",@post+1000) as required_value from table_name;
```

References:

1. for use of variables:
   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html
2. for substring_index:
       https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Comment: Not sure if this answers the question, but **never** read and write the same user variable in the same statement. The order of processing is not guaranteed and hence, the result.

Answer (score 0):

You should normalize the data and store it in a separate table. That said, to answer your question you could use these queries to achieve what you want:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp (val VARCHAR(50));
SET @str = CONCAT("INSERT INTO temp (val) VALUES ('",REPLACE((SELECT org FROM mytable LIMIT 1), ",", "'),('"),"');");
PREPARE st FROM @str;
EXECUTE st;

SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(val, ':', 1), ":", (CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(val, ':', -1) AS UNSIGNED) + 1000)))
FROM temp;
```

Just make sure to replace `SELECT org FROM mytable LIMIT 1` in the above query with your query that returns the string `1:38,25:39,41:101` you need to edit. Be aware that this example only shows how to process the value in one string. If you need to process values of multiple rows, you need to adjust a bit more...

Check sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf6da4/1/0